# How to call an async python function from a non async function

Tags: python

I have a Python function that must be synchronous (non async) that needs to call an async function. Any way of doing it?

Motivation: async foo() is provided by a communication package and bar() is a callback of a GUI framework so I don't have control over their synchronicity but need to bridge the gap, having bar calling foo and using its returned value.

```
async def foo():
   return 'xyz'


def bar():
   value = ... foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) to run a coroutine synchronously:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    return 'xyz'

def bar():
    xyz = asyncio.run(foo())
    print(xyz)
```